# Docker container not accessible through localhost, but accessible through 127.0.0.1

Tags: docker, networking, ipv6, docker-swarm, ipv4

## Problem

I have a Docker service container exposed to `*:8080`.

- I cannot access the container through `localhost:8080`. Chrome / `curl` hangs up indefinitely.
- But I can access the container if I use any other local IP, such as `127.0.0.1`

This is tripping me up because in my `hosts` file, `localhost` redirects to `127.0.0.1`.

Why is this happening? And is it IPv4/IPv6 dual-stack related somehow?

## Environment

I am on PopOS (Ubuntu-based), with Docker Swarm enabled.
I am using this test stack file, `traefik.docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik # The official Traefik docker image
    command: --api --docker # Enables the web UI and tells Traefik to listen to docker
    ports:
      - "80:80"     # The HTTP port
      - "8080:8080" # The Web UI (enabled by --api)
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
```

To run the stack, I use:

```
docker stack deploy -c traefik.docker-compose.yml traefik
```

Once the service is up, I confirm that it is listening to `8080` through 2 ways:

1. `docker service ls`

```
ID                  NAME                    MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE               PORTS
4ejfsvenij3p        traefik_reverse-proxy   replicated          1/1                 traefik:latest      *:80->80/tcp, *:8080->8080/tcp
```

2. `sudo ss -pnlt | grep 8080`

```
LISTEN   3         128                       *:8080                   *:*        users:(("dockerd",pid=2119,fd=45))
```

For reference, here is the contents of my `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
::1     localhost ipv6-localhost
127.0.1.1   pop-os.localdomain  pop-os pop1810x220
```

I just use `curl` for the tests:

- Works: `curl http://127.0.0.1:8080`
- Hangs up: `curl http://localhost:8080`

Comment: How about `curl 'http://[::1]:8080'` (the IPv6 version of `localhost`)?

Comment: No dice, `http://[::1]:8080/` hangs up too

Comment: That's actually what I was *hoping* for -- it tells us what's wrong with `localhost`. Keep in mind that `/etc/hosts` isn't the only piece involved in name resolution -- you need to evaluate your system's NSS modules to know what all the components are in play, so you can't trust that `/etc/hosts` overrides everything else without investigating how your distro (or your sysadmin, if locally overridden) has set up name resolution.

Comment: This opens up a new avenue for investigation, I'll dig more around this, thank you!

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: I still haven't :(

Comment: I got the same issue. However, container deployed by docker run works fine when accessing the ::1. The containers deployed by docker compose or swarm failed to map the external ipv6 to ipv4. If you look at `netstats -tulpn` you will found the normal container was listening via `docker-proxy` while the swarm was listened by `dockerd`. I'm not sure why this causes the difference. Hope an update on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try editing /etc/hosts in the running container to remove the second 'localhost' reference which is on the second line and follows a few spaces after '::1' so that it reads:

::1     ipv6-localhost